# An open subset of a scheme X.

Tags: affine-schemes

Let $(X,O_X)$ scheme and  $f\in{O_X(X)}$ then  $X_f$ is an  open subset of $X$ where
$X_f=\left\{{x\in{X}| f_x\in{u(O_{X,x})}}\right\}$ and $ u(O_{X,x})$is the set of invertible elements.

Proof:

As $x\in{X_f}$ then $f_x\in{u(O_{X,x})}$ then there is a $g_x\in{O_{X,x}}$
 such that

$f_xg_x=1$ implies that exists $x\in U$ and $x\in V$ such that $f\vert_U g\vert_V=1$, so "shrinking" $U$ is take $U\cap V$ and then we can talk about $(fg)\vert_{U\cap V}=1$?

Answer (score 1):

$f_xg_x=1$ is equivlent to saying that there exists an open subset $x\in U$
such that $(fg)_{\mid U}=f_{\mid U}g_{\mid U}=1$ by definition of the stalk. This implies that for every $y\in U, f_yg_y=1$, thus $U\subset X_f$ and henceforth $X_f$ is open.

Comment: Thank you.

My test is not right?

Comment: You have to show that for every $x\in X_f$ there exists an open subset $U$ such that $x\in U\subset X_f$. In your test you don't mention that every element of $U\cap V$ is in $X_f$ although is a consequence of $f_{\mid U}g_{\mid U}=1$